# Accessing files from external hard drive

Tags: vba, excel

I have files stored on a  WD elements hard drive. On occasions I need to copy files from here onto my pc. When I tested the following macro using both the source and destination folders on the c: drive it works fine. However when I changed the source to the external drive (I:\history\june) it says the files do not exist. How can I access the external drive? Any guidance would be welcome.
Thanks, willi

```
Sub CopyFiles()
    Dim iRow As Integer
    Dim sSourcePath As String
    Dim sDestinationPath As String
    Dim sFileType As String

    Dim bContinue As Boolean

    bContinue = True
    iRow = 2

    sSourcePath = "C:\Users\admin\documents\Test1\"
    sDestinationPath = "C:\Users\admin\documents\Test2\"

    sFileType = ".pdf"

    While bContinue

        If Len(Range("B" & CStr(iRow)).Value) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Files Copied"
            bContinue = False
        Else

            If Len(Dir(sSourcePath & Range("B" & CStr(iRow)).Value & sFileType)) = 0 Then
                Range("C" & CStr(iRow)).Value = "File Does Not Exist"
                Range("C" & CStr(iRow)).Font.Bold = True
            Else
                Range("C" & CStr(iRow)).Value = "File Copied"
                Range("C" & CStr(iRow)).Font.Bold = False

                If Trim(sDestinationPath) <> "" Then
                    Dim objFSO
                    Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

                    If objFSO.FolderExists(sDestinationPath) = False Then
                        MsgBox "The destination folder " & sDestinationPath & " Does Not Exists"
                        Exit Sub
                    End If

                    objFSO.CopyFile Source:=sSourcePath & Range("B" & CStr(iRow)).Value & _
                        sFileType, Destination:=sDestinationPath
                End If
            End If
        End If
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this give the output you expect? - `Debug.Print sSourcePath & Range("B" & CStr(iRow)).Value & sFileType`

Comment: Tim, Yes it gives me I:\History\June\.pdf

Comment: That doesn't look valid ?  There's no file name, only an extension.

Comment: Yes that's right, only the extension

Comment: So what's that supposed to do?  FSO doesn't work with wildcard paths (but you don't even have a wildcard character so maybe that's not what you're doing here).  Do you actually have a file named ".pdf" ?  That's not a valid name...

Comment: Problem solved, why are the simplest errors the hardest to find. When I compiled a list of test files, I omitted the file extension. But the live data included the extension so that when the macro ran it added a second file extension.  Thanks for your interest